# NodeMCU LUA ESP8266 12E Issues with Programming

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, breadboard

I recently bought the NodeMCU ESP8266 to work on an embedded project, and for whatever reason, the board will only allow me to upload Arduino sketches when I unplug and replug in the board via the Micro-USB cable. I don't have any jumper wires connected to pins in the board--just the Micro-USB cable. The IDE gives me the following:

```
esptool v0.4.13-1-gf80ae31 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to nodemcu
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from COM1 to COM3
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    espcomm_upload_file
    espcomm_upload_mem
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Like I said, it programs fine when I unplug and replug in the board, but it is quite a nuisance to do this every time. I'd like the board to automatically start running my code after uploading. Here's what I've tried/found:

-I've made sure the baud rates are matching in the device manager and the upload speed tab in the IDE.

-The device is in fact being picked up in the device manager with the correct driver: USB-SERIAL CH340.

-I've tried pressing the flash button before programming.

-I've tried connecting the ground pin on the NodeMCU to GPIO pin 0.

-Tried reinstalling drivers.

-Tried switching boards.

This may also explain why my serial monitor is so inconsistent as well; sometimes it outputs nothing and sometimes it outputs garbage, but that's a separate issue that I won't worry about for now. Can someone please help me out here? I've referenced a lot of other posts on here as well as tutorials but none have helped me thus far.

Thanks

Comment: what board or reset method do you select in Tools menu?

Comment: I selected the NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module) for the board. There is no reset method option unless I select "generic ESP8266 module".